# exclude URL in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to create a filter in Google Analytics, to exclude the following pages:

-- All the pages with names starting from "temp" in the directory mydomain.com/articles/

-- all the pages with names starting from "tmp" in directory mydomain.com/units/

What filter field and pattern do I need?

Comment: Are you trying to filter a page report or attempting at creating a profile (view) level filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use two exclusion filters with regex maching.

URI of request:

/articles/temp(.*)

/units/tmp(.*)